# Jenkins build unable to create thread

Tags: ubuntu, java, jenkins, vps

I've rented a VPS with a provider and installed Jenkins on this server. This VPS has 4 cpu cores and 8GB of RAM, plenty for a build server.
So I installed Jenkins on there and tried running a simple Java build.
But, when I try to run a build, i.e. run `mvn clean package` from the Jenkins server, I get the following error:
`[9,011s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.`

Whenever I run the build from a remote session, this is **not** an issue.

Now, I've looked into this and what I find, is setting the user limit(s), so that is what I did next.
I set the limits in the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file for the jenkins user. So this is what the output of `ulimit -a` shows for the `jenkins` user:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1546779
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 8192
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I was mostly worried about stack size, mem size and user processes so I put that on some, what I believe to be, sensible values.
However, this does not change anything.

One of my coworkers suggested creating a SWAP file, but unfortunately, this is not possible on this VPS so even if that would fix the issue, it is not possible here.

Does anyone have any idea of where to look with this issue?

Comment: Judging strictly upon the Error Message, @ralphcom, "_Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed_", can you please investigate whether you have a certain limit set on the number of threads that may be created?

Comment: Hi, other than using ulimit or the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file, which other limits are there for thread creation?

Comment: Tricky Issues. Not really applicable just to mere Super Users flying boldly through the virtual sky. We would also check the contents of the `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` File. We would also investigate [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078106/pthread-create-fails-with-eagain) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634736/pthread-create-and-eagain). MultiThreaded Programming is _not_ trivial.